Simplifying Computation Subject to Polynomial Equations
I am trying to use Mathematica to simplify sums of the form
$$\sum_{0 \leq j \leq 5}\sum_{0 \leq k \leq 1}\omega^{nj-k},$$ subject to the polynomial equations $\omega^{6} = 1$ and $\omega^{2} = \omega - 1$, with $1 \leq n \leq 5$. Indeed, it follows that, if $nj - k \notin \{0,1\}$, then we may replace every instance of $\omega^{nj - k}$ with some $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $\omega^{m}$, where $m \in \{0,1\}$. For example, $$\omega^{9} = \omega^{6 + 3} = \omega^{3} = \omega \cdot \omega^{2} = \omega(\omega - 1) = \omega^{2} - \omega = \omega - 1 -\omega = -1.$$ Is there a way to write some Mathematica code that implements this procedure? I have made an attempt with the ReplaceAll function, but it is hideous and not elegant at all, and it seems I cannot find anything on the internet concerning my problem.
Thanks!

Could do PolynomialReduce[…,w^2-w+1,w][[2]]. Note that the first relation is already implied by the second, hence is superfluous(were it not, one might use the gcd of the relations since they are univariate).

Use Solve[] and RootReduce[]
omega = Solve[\[Omega]^2 - \[Omega] + 1 == 0 && \[Omega]^6 == 
    1, \[Omega]]


tab = Table[{n, s[n] = Sum[\[Omega]^(n*j - k), {j, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 1}], 
    RootReduce[s[n] /. omega[[1]]], 
    RootReduce[s[n] /. omega[[2]]]}, {n, 1, 5}];
TableForm[tab, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "sum", omega[[1]], omega[[2]]}}]


You can also use PolynomialQuotientReaminder[]:
tab2 = Table[
   S = Sum[\[Omega]^(n*j - k), {j, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 1}];
   {Q, R} = 
    PolynomialQuotientRemainder[
     S*\[Omega]^6, \[Omega]^2 - \[Omega] + 1, \[Omega]];
   {n, S, Q, R}, {n, 1, 5}];
TableForm[tab2, TableHeadings->{None,{"n","S","Q","R"}}]


